# Looping Through All Workbooks in Folder -- Copy and Paste To Master

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a script that should loop through each Workbook in a folder, add a range to a variable and paste it into the master book which contains the code.

My issue is that the Variable FName that should contain the active Workbook isn't being assigned a name (it's always "") and I'm not sure what wrong with my Dir function.

Below is my Code:

```
Sub StuffYourLendersInMyMouth()

Dim MasterBook As Workbook
Dim CurrentBook As Workbook
Dim MasterSheet As Worksheet
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Dim FilePath As Variant
Dim FName As Variant

Dim MasterLR As Double
Dim CurrentLR As Double

Dim LenderCol As Integer
Dim LoanCol As Integer
Dim DateCol As Integer
Dim PropCol As Integer
Dim AddCol As Integer

Dim CopyRng1 As Variant
Dim CopyRng2 As Variant
Dim CopyRng3 As Variant
Dim CopyRng4 As Variant
Dim CopyRng5 As Variant

'Dim LenderCol As Integer
'Dim LoanCol As Integer
'Dim DateCol As Integer
'Dim PropCol As Integer
'Dim AddCol As Integer


'Set Objects
Set MasterBook = Workbooks("Bend_Lender_List.xlsm")
Set MasterSheet = MasterBook.Worksheets("Master_List")

'Define Variables
FilePath = Dir("C:\Users\James\OneDrive\Desktop\Title_Lenders\")
FName = Dir(FilePath & ".xlsx")
MasterLR = 2
CurrentLR = 10

LenderCol = 1
LoanCol = 2
DateCol = 5
PropCol = 10
AddCol = 11

Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled

If Right(FilePath, 1) <> "\" Then FilePath = FilePath & "\"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

While FName <> ""

    MasterLR = MasterSheet.Cells(MasterSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set CurrentBook = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FilePath & FName)
    Set CurrentSheet = CurrentBook.Sheets(1)
    CurrentLR = CurrentSheet.Cells(CurrentSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    CopyRng1 = CurrentBook.Range(CurrentBook.Cells(10, LenderCol), CurrentBook.Cells(CurrentLR, LenderCol))
    CopyRng2 = CurrentBook.Range(CurrentBook.Cells(10, LoanCol), CurrentBook.Cells(CurrentLR, LoanCol))
    CopyRng3 = CurrentBook.Range(CurrentBook.Cells(10, DateCol), CurrentBook.Cells(CurrentLR, DateCol))
    CopyRng4 = CurrentBook.Range(CurrentBook.Cells(10, PropCol), CurrentBook.Cells(CurrentLR, PropCol))
    CopyRng5 = CurrentBook.Range(CurrentBook.Cells(10, AddCol), CurrentBook.Cells(CurrentLR, AddCol))
    
    Masterlist.Range(Masterlist.Cells(10, 1), Masterlist.Cells(MasterLR, 1)) = CopyRng1
    Masterlist.Range(Masterlist.Cells(10, 2), Masterlist.Cells(MasterLR, 2)) = CopyRng2
    Masterlist.Range(Masterlist.Cells(10, 3), Masterlist.Cells(MasterLR, 3)) = CopyRng3
    Masterlist.Range(Masterlist.Cells(10, 4), Masterlist.Cells(MasterLR, 4)) = CopyRng4
    Masterlist.Range(Masterlist.Cells(10, 5), Masterlist.Cells(MasterLR, 5)) = CopyRng5

    FName = Dir

    CurrentBook.Close
    'MasterLR = MasterLR + 1

Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: `FName = Dir(FilePath & "*.xlsx")`

Comment: and filepath should only be: `FilePath = "C:\Users\James\OneDrive\Desktop\Title_Lenders\")`

Comment: `FilePath` should be the folder location only.  It then gets concatenated with the wildcard and file ending to pull a list of the xlsx files.